# Use Signal to pass QImage from a Worker Thread to Main UI Thread to Display in pyqt5 GUI (Python)

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-multithreading, signals-slots, qimage

I'm trying to define my own signal to display QImage (converted from raw data) upon a button press. The GUI has a button called as connect, and a QLabel that's named as DisplayRect.
I'd like to draw this QImage on DisplayRect. The code below prints 'signal received' upon pressing the connect button. I'd like to make it pass QImage so that I can **self.DisplayRect.setPixmap(the passed QImage )**
Please have a look:

```
class DPSignal(QObject):
    dpsig = pyqtSignal()
    
    def run(self):
        self.dpsig.emit()
        
        
        
class DisplayThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        
        
    def run(self):
        dps = DPSignal()
        dps.dpsig.connect(self.parent.dpupdate)
        dps.run
        
class WindowClass(QMainWindow, form_class):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUI(self)
        
       self.connectButton.clicked.connect(self.connectFunction)
       
       
       
       
       
    @pyqtSlot()
    def connectFunction(self):
        dpThread = DisplayThread(self)
        dpThread.start()
        
    def dpupdate(self):
        print("signal received")
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myWindow = WindowClass()
    myWindow.show()
    app.exec_()
```

This piece of code below reads binary data from a file and I'd like to add this code to somewhere in DisplayThread so that it passes the processed QImage to the main UI thread. Then main UI thread can (I suppose) self.DisplayRect.setPixmap to display. Thanks for reading!

```
raw = rawpy.imread(...path...)
src = raw.postprocess()
buf = src.data.tobytes()
h, w, ch = src.shape
bytesperline = ch * whileimage = QImage(buf, 1024, 768, bytesperline, QImage.Format_RGB888)

self.DisplayRect.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))
self.DisplayRect.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try move the preprocessing logic to the `DisplayThread` and in the `run` method. Then transfer the raw bytes through the signal to the Main Window and create and show the image from the Main Window.

```
class DisplayThread(QThread):
    dpsig = pyqtSignal([bytes, int])

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()
        self.parent = parent

    def run(self):
        raw = rawpy.imread("./file.nef")
        src = raw.postprocess()
        buf = src.data.tobytes()
        h, w, ch = raw.shape
        bpl = w * ch
        self.dpsig.emit(buf, bpl)

class WindowClass(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.connectButton.clicked.connect(self.connectFunction)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def connectFunction(self):
        self.dpThread = DisplayThread(self)
        self.dpThread.dpsig.connect(self.dpupdate)
        self.dpThread.finished.connect(self.dpThread.deleteLater)
        self.dpThread.start()

    def dpupdate(self, buf, bpl):
        print("signal received")
        image = QImage(buf, 1024, 768, bpl, QImage.Format.Format_RGB888)
        self.DisplayRect.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))
        self.DisplayRect.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myWindow = WindowClass()
    myWindow.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Why? A thread subclass already exists, and there's no point for a further object.

Comment: IDK what you mean... I merged the logic that the OP had split into the QThread subclass with the `DPSignal` object.  So then there is no need to subclass QThread.  The rest of it is pretty much all the OP's code @musicamante

Comment: As long as there's no need for a local event loop for the thread, there's no point in creating a subclass of QObject and a separate QThread that require a `moveToThread()` (which can also create some confusion with PyQt under certain situations, and is often cause of issues with their inter-connected signals and slots). A QThread subclass will generally simplify the code both in the class itself and in its instance creation and start.

Comment: @musicamante  So you are saying that instead of merging the code into the qobject i should have merged it into the qthread and dropped the object?

Comment: Yes. Note: it's not that you *have* to do that, as using the QObject/moveToThread approach *is* valid. But, in most cases, it's actually simpler, considering the mechanics behind python (the notorious and infamous GIL). There *are* differences, though: if you connect a signal to a slot of a QObject moved to a thread, that signal will be queued (and executed in the target thread), while doing it with a QThread subclass causes the slot being called immediately (in the caller thread). Depending on your needs, you might choose one approach or the other, but if direct interaction with the thread ->

Comment: -> required after it's being started, it's common practice to use a QThread (with a Queue object, if data communication *to* the thread is necessary). Alternatively, the QObject approach can still achieve the same as long as the signal connection is forced to `DirectConnection` (instead of the standard `AutoConnection` which checks for thread affinity). Both methods are valid, it depends on your needs. I suggest you to read [this](//stackoverflow.com/q/50622536/2001654) post and its answers: while it's for C++, the basic concepts are the same (except for the GIL matter).